# onClick populated by variable without triggering it

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I want to append this to my document:

```
$('#myDiv).append("<div id='myDiv2' onclick="+extElementConfig.onClickDo+">Do</div>");
```

The snippet above has it's `onClick` populated by a certain object with properties,
this:

```
var extElementConfig={onClickDo:sampleFunc()};
```

Unfortunately declaring a function into the object property also fires it, as was expected.

> How can I achieve the above functionality without triggering the
>   sampleFunc()?
>       I just need to dynamically populate the onClick event through an object property.

Comment: Using jquery and using inline events? Don't do it!

Comment: This is intentional..

Comment: Why is it intentional?

Comment: @epascarello thanks for asking, i'm thinking twice over why it is, which means it probably shouldn't

Comment: I have coded it the way you have for certain cases, but most times it can be avoided with event bubbling or attaching events the unobtrusive way. Below shows a solution that is sort of what I think you were after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have control over the `extElementConfig` object, remove the parenthesis from `sampleFunc`

```
var extElementConfig={extElementPosition :10,extElementId:'mailOrderBtn',onClickDo:sampleFunc};
```

Comment: beat me to it by a few seconds... :)

Comment: and what If I have parameters for the function as well?

Comment: The approach I would suggest depends on where the arguments would be coming from, but most likely `bind` would work well for this.

Comment: so no silver bullet for me. That case cannot be done in an object property, right?

Comment: It can be done, what arguments would you want to pass? Can you clarify your use case?

Comment: It's an extension template which means they can be any kind of arguments. People might use what I write above to declare any kind of them. So I don't really know. I have this example though `onClickDo:debouncer(debouncer_func, 250)`

Comment: They would have to use a closure `onClickDo: function() { debouncer(debouncer_func, 250) }`

Comment: @epascarello is correct, you need to wrap the `onClickDo` callback in a closure and use apply to call it with variable arguments.

Answer (score 0):

As Rob. M. pointed out the real problem with your code was the fact you were running the code when it was in the object instead of assigning a reference. And when you tried to assigning the onclick, that had issues too since you are trying to use a function reference when it was a string.

To get your code to run, it would be something like

```js
function sampleFunc () {
  alert("clicked");
}

var extElementConfig={onClickDo:"sampleFunc()"}; 

$('#myDiv').append("<div id='myDiv2' onclick='"+extElementConfig.onClickDo+"()'>Do</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

---

To get rid of this, do not use the sting method to build up the element, instead leverage the power of jQuery. Below is an example where I build a div and pass in some arguments to change the element's text and css when clicked.

```js
    function sampleFunc(txt, css) {
        $(this).text(txt).css(css);
    }
    
    var extElementConfig = {
        onClickDo: sampleFunc,
        onClickArgs : ["Clicked", {"background-color":"green"}]
    };
    
    $('<div/>', {
            id: 'myDiv2',
            text: 'Do!'
        }
    ).on("click", 
        function() {  
             extElementConfig.onClickDo.apply(this, extElementConfig.onClickArgs); 
        } 
    ).appendTo("#myDiv");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```